# saving content block for email header breaks layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I try to copy header and footer of email to cms block. There are some tags that are open in one block (header) and closed in other block (footer).
But when I edit cms block layout is broken as magento tries to close tags in header that are not closed. Could you please tell how to solve this issue?

{{block type="cms/block" block_id="test_header" }}
{{block type="core/template" area="frontend" template="general/email/adminNotification.phtml" content=$content}}
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="test_footer" }}

Comment: Make sure you are not using the wysiwyg editor when editing cms block. I use the same approach and have had no problem with closing tags in a cms block.

Comment: I thought about it but people who work with it want to use wysiwy editor.

Comment: That will be your problem, it will close tags for you.